# Where could I find a fedimint custodian on the web? Where to look for one?

Tags: custody, fedimint

It is written at ***[fedimint.org](https://fedimint.org/docs/GettingStarted/Why-Fedimint)***:

> Fedimint aims to address this by distributing custodianship across millions of communities, making it simple for them to bank themselves. These community focused 'banks' are known as Fedimint Federations.[...]
>
> Fedimint allows bitcoiners to onboard new users, assisting them in their custody and payment model. Instead of referring a new bitcoiner to a third party custodian, you can onboard them yourself as part of a Federation.
>
> Put another way it allows you to be your mum's / friends / villages bank.

I don't have friends. Most of the human interactions that I have are those on sites such as ***bitcoin.stackexchange.com***. Is there an online, be it on the clearnet or an onion network, list of fedimint federations, akin to the lists of servers of other federated systems, such [cashu](https://fedimint.org/docs/GettingStarted/Why-Fedimint), [XMPP](https://providers.xmpp.net/), or [nostr](https://nostr.watch/relays/find)?